# IWebBrowser2::Navigate2 occasionally freezes when opening several new tabs

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-8, excel-2007

I'm writing an Excel script to open a list of PDFs in Internet Explorer tabs. It works fine most of the time, but occasionally *when I try to close my browser window, a few of the tabs will close, then it stops and all IE instances will freeze*, so I have to kill them all in Task Manager. *Note that I can avoid the problem by closing each tab individually*.

I'm running IE8 and Excel 2007, for the record. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ShowBrowserWarning
    Dim TheHTML As String, PDFs, PDF, First, SerialValue, Test, k
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Count = 1 Then
        ' Get the serial number from the adjacent column
        SerialValue = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1)
        TheHTML = ShowHTML("http://ucmwww.dnr.state.la.us/ucmsearch/findAllDocuments.aspx?brief=False&query=xwellserialnumber+LIKE+'" & SerialValue & "'+AND+xdocumenttype+LIKE+'WELL ENGINEERING/MECHANICAL'&format=HTML&sortfield=xdate")
        Set PDFs = ExtractPDFs(TheHTML)
        If PDFs Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No associated well engineering/mechanical PDFs."
        Else
            First = True
            Dim ie As Object
            Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            ie.Visible = True
            For Each PDF In PDFs
                'While ie.Busy
                '    Dim testvar
                '    testvar = 1 + 1
                'Wend
                If First Then
                    ' Open new IE window
                    ie.Navigate2 PDF.Value
                    First = False
                Else
                    ' Open tab in existing IE window
                    ie.Navigate2 PDF.Value, 2048
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What gives? Why does it freeze like that? Does it have anything to do [this issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/internet-explorer-automation-protected-mode-lcie-default-integrity-level-medium.aspx)? (Please try not to laugh at my ignorance!) Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: see the italicized text above. I didn't quite describe the problem accurately!

Comment: have you noticed any similar patterns for when it freezes?

Comment: can you think of any ways that it may get caught in an unending loop?

Comment: No, I don't think there's any chance of an infinite loop in my code. The problem still happens when it opens, say, three links. I've updated my question, though--please see the italicized text. I didn't quite describe it accurately.

Comment: Is the macro still running at the time of closing the explore windows? After several of the explore tabs close does it freeze on a specific explore tab each time that happens?

Comment: Also, do you have any code that is event driven in the macro?

Comment: Yes, this bit of code is event driven. I made it so that double-clicking on a cell within a certain column opens up corresponding PDFs--so it's within Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick. So I believe it's possible that the macro is still running. And I think it freezes on a specific tab. I'll update the code above to show you my whole BeforeDoubleClick function.

Comment: you may want to find an error that you can reproduce, then once you've found it, debug through the code and find where the error occurs. However, it does sound to me like the macro is somehow getting caught running forever somehow. But it seems like it would be connected to the event driven code. Let me know if you make any new discoveries

Comment: Well, I added a "finished!" messagebox at the end of my double-click event handler. Apparently, it only says it's finished after I click back on Excel. However, even after doing that IE has those strange errors. In fact, even after exiting out of Excel entirely and trying to close IE it sometimes freezes. Strange. I think the probability of it freezing is related to the number of tabs it opens, but sometimes it freezes with few tabs running, and I don't think which file it's opening matters.

Comment: hmm..It could just be that IE sucks. have you tried leaving it after you run it for awhile to see if it will finish thinking and not have trouble closing? It could be that the computer is still trying to process a bunch of stuff. Maybe the process takes longer than we think? keep up the good work with troubleshooting. you're gaining ground

Comment: Yes, I think that's the root of the issue. I find, though, that the issue can be avoided if I close each browser tab individually, so I'll have to go with that solution now as this program is only being used by three people including myself. Please, though, don't hesitate to let me know if you think of anything else, and thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

And what about Browser-Busy check? Could it help to avoid the issue?

```
    For Each PDF In PDFs

        While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend

        If First Then
            ' Open new IE window
            ie.Navigate2 PDF.Value
            First = False
        Else
            ' Open tab in existing IE window
            ie.Navigate2 PDF.Value, 2048
        End If
    Next
```

Or just wait between the browser.Navigate calls for a while to give the browser enough time to load one dokument before starting to load next one. Try different time-periods and watch if the freezing issue could be avoided this way.

```
For Each PDF In PDFs

  DoEventsForTimePeriod timePeriodInSeconds:=15 ' try different time periods here

  If First Then
  ' Open new IE window
  ie.Navigate2 PDF.Value
  First = False
  Else
  ' Open tab in existing IE window
  ie.Navigate2 PDF.Value, 2048
  End If
Next

Private Sub DoEventsForTimePeriod(ByVal timePeriodInSeconds As Single)
    ' VBA.Timer: Returns a Single representing the number of seconds elapsed since midnight.
    Dim pause As Single: pause = VBA.Timer + timePeriodInSeconds
    Do While VBA.Timer < pause
        DoEvents ' Yield to other processes.
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @slothario you may also want to try adding in some browser-busy statements and seeing what kind of help/change that brings.

Comment: What do you mean? What other kinds of browser busy statements should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I´m new too but, as far as can see, I would set ie = Nothing at the end of the sub to loose any relation between VBA and InternetExplorer Application